# How do I read registry keys from a Desktop App

Tags: c#

I am reading a registry key to get the local install path for a program. The key is read properly and returned when running from a console app.
When calling the same method from a Windows Desktop App, the key is empty.

I'm at a loss. I have a console app project that calls the method and gets the proper key value.
The Form1 app calls the method, but the values it returns is empty. Same exact code.

```
result = String)Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\SoftwareName\\SoftwareName", "Directory", null);
```

I expect the output to be `C:\software` when it is just empty.

Comment: You code wouldn't compile as is. Are you sure this is the code you have in your app?

Comment: I deleted the '(' when pasting the code in.

Comment: Don't use Wow6432Node explicitly.  Use [this instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?view=netframework-4.8), specifying RegistryView.Registry32.  Now the project's platform target no longer matters.  The every-programmer-needs-to-know-this article [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector).

Comment: This is the method: https://pastebin.com/4qZXzfWB

Comment: I was having issues earlier with the framework during my initial build. Thanks for the artical HansPassant